# enabling a text area with new text added through AngularJS to scroll

Tags: html, angularjs, scroll, haml

I have a simple "chat-like" app where AngularJS is used to append both the input and response in a chat area:

```
 %div{:id => 'chat-area'}
  %img{:src => '/images/chat-image.png', 'ng-show'=> 'chats.length === 0'}
  %ul
    %li{'ng-repeat'=> 'chat in chats track by $index', 'ng-class'=> 'mainCtrl.getMessageStyle(chat)'} 
      {{chat.user}}: {{chat.message}}

  -#  %p {{newChat}}    
  %input{'type' => 'text', :id => 'type-here-box', 'placeholder' => 'type here or click link on right' , 'ng-model'=>'newChat', 'ng-keyup' => "$event.keyCode == 13 && submitData()"}

  %button{'ng-click' => "submitData()", "style" => "position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"}
```

**The problem**:  When the 'chat in chats' extends to the bottom of the screen, it is hidden by the `%input` field --- what I want it to do is scroll.

How do I do that?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22407177/3199781

Comment: @AnthonyChu thanks, let me check

Comment: @AnthonyChu -- this looks like it should, but I'm not sure how to deploy it from the example...it looks like I take the scrollglue.js and add it to my site and then just add the directive to the container...

Comment: Make sure you add `'luegg.directives'` as a module dependency (e.g., `angular.module('myApp', ['luegg.directives']);`

Comment: @AnthonyChu  oh, wow, I missed that! btw, I use haml so not sure how to add the scroll-glue to my div...would you know?

Comment: Sorry don't know much about haml. You need to figure out how to emit to the HTML an empty `scroll-glue` attribute or `scroll-glue=""`.

Comment: @AnthonyChu yeah...trying to see how, but getting errors, thanks....

Comment: @AnthonyChu hm, the instructions didn't mention to add the luegg.directdives....it said I just need to add scroll-glue...are the instructions wrong and I should add the module dependency?

Comment: Take a look at the demo code... I think you can see they added it as a dependency.

Comment: @AnthonyChu yes, I just did and you were write....the documentation is wrong!  I did what you said....and it works, now, thank you!

Comment: Can you create an answer so I can award it to you for future questions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a height to the ul and also give overflow: auto in CSS.

**CSS for UL**

```
ul {
   height: 85px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

**Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/xo18ghg6/1/)**

Comment: scroll will appear only when the content goes beyond the height mentioned in the CSS

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/xo18ghg6/2/) and click on the button multiple times to add element more than the content area

Comment: is it possible angularjs is making it behave differently?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you create a fiddle with HTML generated for the above and the styles applied to those elements?

Comment: Yeah let me see if I can do that

Comment: There's no easy way to do this.  I can't use "view source" since it's all added in the DOM.  I have a feeling that the AngularJS is what is causing the problem.  Here is a screenshot which shows the CSS and that it's not working: http://cl.ly/image/0G143T1g2w0Q

Comment: Chances are that the CSS is getting overwritten. Try [this CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/xo18ghg6/3/). Am forcing the `ul` to get the height by giving `!important` in CSS just to know if it's getting overwritten.